# Scipy - AttributeError - 'lti object has no attribute bode'

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, attributeerror

I was trying the following example from the [`scipy` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lti.bode.html#scipy.signal.lti.bode).

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s1 = signal.lti([1], [1, 1])
w, mag, phase = s1.bode()
plt.figure()
plt.semilogx(w, mag)    # Bode magnitude plot
plt.figure()
plt.semilogx(w, phase)  # Bode phase plot
plt.show()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scipy-test.py", line 5, in <module>
    w, mag, phase = s1.bode()
AttributeError: 'lti' object has no attribute 'bode'
```

Comment: Which version are you using - try `print(scipy.__version__)`.

Comment: `bode` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lti.bode.html) was added in scipy version 0.11.0.

Comment: That was the problem, I installed 0.14.0 and it works. Thanks.